# Estimating Studentized Residuals (or Another Similar Measure) After Linear Regression With Robust Standard Errors

Tags: multiple-regression, stata, residuals, robust-standard-error

I have estimated a linear multiple regression with robust standard errors using Stata (`regress depvar indepvar1 indepvar2 indepvar3 indepvar4 indepvar5, robust`).

Given that I've used robust standard errors, Stata doesn't allow me to estimate studentized residuals. I haven't found a technical note explaining why this is the case, but I believe that studentized residuals are not a statistically well-defined concept after an estimation with robust standard errors.

Is there any other way in which I could obtain a measure such as studentized residuals after linear multiple regression with robust standard errors? I am especially interested in comparing the residuals of the observations in my dataset and seeing whether they seem to fall above or below the model prediction.

Comment: Your Stata syntax example was illegal. It's incidental to the question, so I edited it.

Comment: I don't think you need Studentized residuals to see whether values fall above or below model predictions. Any flavour of residuals would do that.

Comment: Thanks for your responses @NickCox! Perhaps I didn't specify my question well enough: as internally studentized residuals are the 'normal' residuals divided by their standard deviation (without removing the observation in question), they allow you to see whether the residuals of certain observations are more or less than the expected frequency. Ie, if the int studentized residual is larger than 2 or smaller than -2, the observation's value is larger/smaller than predicted by the model. I thought that only studentized residuals use this scale, where 2 and -2 mark area for normal residuals.

Comment: I don't understand your extra point. The question clearly states interest in what is above or below prediction. The precise scale of residuals is secondary and even at best +2 and -2 don't mark any kind of formal confidence limits, if that is what you are seeking.  What you mean by "expected frequency" here?

Comment: Thanks again for your quick comment @NickCox! Some materials that I've come across seem to state that for internally studentized residuals, values between 2 and -2 contain normal residuals, and any with absolute values larger than that are significantly bigger/smaller. I wanted to be able to look at the studentized residuals from my model and evaluate whether they're above or below this 2 and -2 region. I think that this would allow me to say that eg. the observation with a studentized residual 3 has a higher value on their dependent variable than would be predicted by the model.

Comment: However, the residuals I can predict after using the robust standard errors are calculated differently and I don't think I can do a similar analysis with them, which is why I am seeking a measure like studentized residuals.

Comment: Sorry, but evidently I'm missing your point. As you say, Stata won't calculate these residuals given `vce(robust)`. I am saying that you lose no real capability for diagnostic checking.

Comment: @NickCox I do think that the residuals that I get after the robust errors cannot be used in the same way as the studentized ones as all of them range between 5 and 16, and the idea of 'normal studentized residuals' being between 2 and -2 doesn't apply.

Comment: If all your residuals are positive, something else is wrong, I suspect. Can you post your data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32010/discussion-between-sannita-and-nick-cox).

Comment: No thanks; taking it private reduces visibility for other people who might be interested. I don't think I can add more unless you show your data in any case.

Comment: My apologies - I was following a prompt that said the discussion was too  long for comments. How do I go about posting my data on this discussion? Would a dropbox link work?

Comment: You don't have to apologise; some people go off into chat rooms. but it's my personal policy not to do that. The editor for editing posts has various icons. I can't easily say which are visible to you. But it's best to post in a file format that non-Stata users can read.

Comment: Actually, I just realized I had a syntax error, which is why the residuals showed up strange! I typed "predict residuals" expecting that residuals will be predicted when in fact I just created a variable with model predictions called residuals. Now that I realized it and typed "predict residuals, residuals", I am actually getting a variable called residuals with the residuals that are both negative and positive in it.. Gosh, sorry for waisting your time!

Comment: However, as I am still interested to consider which of these 'normal residuals after robust errors' are within the normal spread of residuals and which are somewhat higher or lower, you were saying that there are no formal confidence limits that I could follow?

Comment: As stated at the outset, Stata gives up on that; and I don't have a different answer. In any case, assuming that your residuals follow some well-behaved distribution is not consistent to me with checking them for anomalies, which is I take it your interest here.

Comment: Sign of residuals: that is good news.